# How do I hide/change my name account from start in windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-11

I want to hide my name from start in windows 11
I searched everywhere in the setting, no option for that or for changing the name.

Is there any way I can hide it or change it?

[here is the location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbmJh.png)

Comment: Your name is (99% of the time) your login ID. So hiding your login id is not natively possible so far as I know. Hacks for this kind of stuff often breaks the operating system and so holds no interest for me.

Comment: @John I just don't want to show my real name while recording videos for youtube..

Comment: Normally I go to You Tube, this site, Zoom and so on and just use my first name. No fall out at this point.

Comment: @John I just change it :)

Comment: "Is there any way I can hide it?" - No; It wasn't possible on Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, or Windows 8 and Windows 10. Your name and/or username has always been displayed in the start menu as long as it has existed.  You can certainly change it to something else though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,

1. Go to Microsoft website.
2. Setting.
3. Account.
4. Change nickname.
5. Restart your computer, and done.

Comment: Not finding a "Change Nickname" option here https://account.microsoft.com/ 

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it can be solved by changing the Nickname of the Microsoft account. but, I made a tool to change the Nickname of the start menu without changing the setting of the Microsoft account. I don't know if there is demand.

Download Link:
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/ulhlni2uaii9pfd/Privacy11_v2.1.zip

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1168797)

Comment: Hi, after I use this program, if I lock the screen and click on "forgot pin code", it doesn't show me "login with password", but it pops up a small window that looks like a web page to log me in (sadly, the web page stays white and I can't connect to any network), I want to know what this program is doing to hide the username and what effect it has on my computer, and how I can restore my computer to its original state when I don't need it any more.

Comment: I would like to know what ways this program uses to hide the username, what it modifies in my computer, and how I can restore my computer to its original state when I don't need it anymore.

Neither the manual nor the web page of the program mentions this.

Comment: Now I can't log in to my computer with my password by clicking on "forgot pin code" anyway, it's very annoying, I hope to hear from you soon, otherwise I will feel very insecure....

Comment: And since I can't find anything about Privacy11_v2.1 on the web, I can't fix this problem myself.